# Create a plot to see the distribution relationship between groups of data in R

Tags: r

I have a table like the one below and i want to create a plot in R to see the relationship in T1 and T2 based on counts. on x-axes to have samples with T1 and on y-axes samples with T2 and see the line of counts.A scatter plot would be useful?

```
Sample  Time  counts 
001_T1   T1    26,629,556  
001_T2   T2    20,755,896
002_T1   T1    26,081,538        
002_T2   T2    28,675,076       
003_T1   T1    25,459,034       
003_T2   T2    25,531,900        
004_T1   T1    29,062,968        
004_T2   T2    26,612,567         
005_T1   T1    26,689,387         
005_T2   T2    28,428,044
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please share your data set with `dput`.

Comment: Can you explain why the "counts" column have three different numbers, and if you want these to be evaluated separately?

Comment: No this is one number its just a mistake of ,

Comment: Assuming the name of data frame is Data and column name remains same as the example provided by you. For finding the relationship between T1 and T2 you may find correlation or create a scatter plot between T1 and T2.

For correlation you may use `cor(x = Data[Data$Time == 'T1', "counts"], y = Data[Data$Time == 'T2', "counts"])` and for scatterplot you may use `plot(x = Data[Data$Time == 'T1', "counts"], y = Data[Data$Time == 'T2', "counts"], type = 'b', 
    xlab = 'Sample of T1', ylab = 'Sample of T2')`

Comment: 'x' must be numeric this is the error i get so i suppose it should be transformed as numeric. now the typeof(Data[Data$Time == 'T1', "counts"])  is "character". but when i do as.numeric it returns NAs